# Safe Module Audit Status

Tags: gnosis-safe, audit

I am building a product using Safe and am interested in using Safe Modules and Guards, but as these introduce possible vulnerabilities by granting a contract root access to a Safe account, I am curious as to the audit status of any basic Safe Modules. I would like to maintain as much security as possible.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? You should audit the module; that's correct. But I am not sure whether it's what you asked

Comment: Hi @mikheevm, my question is whether there are any already created and audited Safe Modules available for public use that do generic actions such as to transfer ownership of a Safe or to dispense tokens in some automated way from the Safe